# angular hiding passwords using visibility

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was working with this feature where there is password and confirm password , each field has a hide/eye function to show and hide password but the issue is the second eye or hide or on confirm password does not work but works fine on the password

The confirm new password does not hide and unhide , anyone has an idea on why and how ?

#screenshot
[image]

#html code

```
 <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>New password</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="password" type="{{(showPassword === false)?'password':'text'}}" />
            <mat-icon matSuffix style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="toggleShowPassword()">
              {{!showPassword?'visibility':'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
            <mat-error *ngIf="password.hasError('required')">
              {{errFormMsg.REQUIRED}}
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Confirm new password</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="confirmPassword"
              type="{{(showPassword === false)?'confirmPassword':'text'}}" />
            <mat-icon matSuffix style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="toggleShowPassword()">
              {{!showPassword?'visibility':'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
            <mat-error *ngIf="confirmPassword.hasError('required')">
              {{errFormMsg.REQUIRED}}
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="signupForm.get('confirmPassword').hasError('notEqual')">
              Password does not match
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
```

#ts code

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  accountId: any;
  email: string;
  isInProgress: boolean;
  signupForm: FormGroup;
  hasSubmit = false;
  apiErrMsg = null;
  errFormMsg = ERR_FORM_MSG;
  labels = LABELS;
  isRemembered = false;
  showPassword = false;
  isLoggingIn = false;
  code: string;
  generalStatus = FormStatus.LOGIN;
  securedEmail: string;
  showVerificationSuccessMessage: boolean;
  data: any;
  
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private userService: UserService,
    private _userProfileService: UserProfileService,
    private _notificationService: NotificationService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private route: Router,
    private router: ActivatedRoute,
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ) {
    this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
      confirmPassword: [
        '',
        [Validators.required, this.equalWithPasswordValidator.bind(this)],
      ],
      password: [
        '',
        [
          this.validatePasswordRequired,
          this.validateMinimumPassword,
          this.validatePasswordUpperCase,
          this.validatePasswordLowerCase,
          this.validatePasswordSpecialCharacter,
          this.validateOneNumber,
        ],
      ],
    });
  }

  
  toggleShowPassword() {
    this.showPassword = !this.showPassword;
    console.log("this.showPassword" , this.showPassword)
  }

  get password() {
    return this.signupForm.controls['password'];
  }
  get confirmPassword() {
    return this.signupForm.controls['confirmPassword'];
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input `type` and `formControlName` do not need to match. `type` defines the type of input and `formControlName` defines the name of form control. Your input should be either of type `'password'` or `'text'`

You have incorrectly defined the confirm password type as

```
type="{{(showPassword === false)?'confirmPassword':'text'}}"
```

This will make the input type as `'confirmPassword'`. There is no input type type `'confirmPassword'`. It should be

```
type="{{(showPassword === false)?'password':'text'}}"
```

Your confirm password input should be defined as below

```
<input matInput formControlName="confirmPassword"
       type="{{(showPassword === false)?'password':'text'}}" />
```

**Edit : ** If you want to perfom the toggle functionality seperatly, you could use two variables for toggling password and confirm password.

Sample Implementation

`component.ts`

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  .
  .
  showPassword = false;
  showConfirmPassword = false;
  .
  .
  toggleShowPassword(showBoolean) {
    showBoolean = !showBoolean;
  }
}
```

`component.html`

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>New password</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="password" type="{{(showPassword === false)?'password':'text'}}" />
  <mat-icon matSuffix style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="toggleShowPassword(showPassword)">
    {{!showPassword?'visibility':'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
  <mat-error *ngIf="password.hasError('required')">
    {{errFormMsg.REQUIRED}}
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Confirm new password</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="confirmPassword" type="{{(showConfirmPassword === false)?'password':'text'}}" />
  <mat-icon matSuffix style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="toggleShowPassword(showConfirmPassword)">
    {{!showConfirmPassword?'visibility':'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
  <mat-error *ngIf="confirmPassword.hasError('required')">
    {{errFormMsg.REQUIRED}}
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="signupForm.get('confirmPassword').hasError('notEqual')">
    Password does not match
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: What do you mean ? can you clarify ?

Comment: what I want is that each field has a show/hide password , if user only show the confirm password field then it should only show the conform password field and not both at the same time

Comment: You are using only one class variable `showPassword ` for toggling the input type. You need to have much changes for this.

Comment: Do you have more than two inputs?

Comment: do you have example Sir if I wanted to have each showPassword for each field ?

Comment: only password and confirm password

Comment: if user click the eye on confirm password then it should only hide and show the password on confirm password and not on both

Comment: @BrindaAnand Please check the updated answer

Comment: I tried implementing the solution above Sir , but it does not work

Comment: it does return the boolean but it does not show and hide password SIr

Comment: @BrindaAnand Is the boolean getting updated as expected?

Comment: inst it supposed to be showPassword = showBoolean ?

Comment: What `toggleShowPassword` does is it accepts two class variables, `showPassword` for first input and `showConfirmPassword` for second input. It toggles its value. If it is false, it will be set to true, if true it will be set to false. These booleans are set as the condition to show the icons. Hope this is what you are looking for.